# Why did the number 4 after adding the symbol “0” become the symbol “4”?

Tags: c

I wrote a program that prints the same number that was passed as an argument. The code works, but I don't understand the process of converting numbers to characters. How does this work at the machine level? Why, when I add the zero symbol, do I get the four symbol from the number 4?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void    ft_putnbr(int nb)
{
    if (nb >= 10)
    {
        ft_putnbr(nb / 10);
        ft_putnbr(nb % 10);
    }
    else
    {
        ft_putchar(nb + '0');
    }
}

int main()
{
    ft_putnbr(42);
    return 0;
}
```

I don’t understand the process of converting a number into a symbol in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'0'` is just the human readable represetation of the integer 48 which is considered as code for the character `'0'` in [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

ASCII digit codes:

| decimal | octal | hex | binary | character |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 48 | 060 | 30 | 0110000 | 0 |
| 49 | 061 | 31 | 0110001 | 1 |
| 50 | 062 | 32 | 0110010 | 2 |
| 51 | 063 | 33 | 0110011 | 3 |
| 52 | 064 | 34 | 0110100 | 4 |
| 53 | 065 | 35 | 0110101 | 5 |
| 54 | 066 | 36 | 0110110 | 6 |
| 55 | 067 | 37 | 0110111 | 7 |
| 56 | 070 | 38 | 0111000 | 8 |
| 57 | 071 | 39 | 0111001 | 9 |

When you add `4` to `48` which is integer representation of `'0'` you are getting `52`.

When you write it to the screen then the character represented by its code is displayed (in this case `'4'`)

Also C standard guarantees that digit characters codes will be consecutive and ordered the natural way (ie `'0'` lowest value and `'9'` the highest)

Comment: Not only true on ASCII systems - the C language requires that whatever run-time character coding is used, that the digits `'0'` to `'9'` must be consecutive.

Answer (score 2):

The C language guarantees that the character codes for the digits 0 to 9 must be consecutive:

> the 10 decimal digits: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
>
> ⋮
>
> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after `0` in the above
> list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

That means that `'1'` == `'0' + 1`, and `'2'` == `'1' + 1`, and `'3'` == `'2' + 1`, and so on.

With that knowledge, it's fairly easy to deduce that

`'4'` == `'3' + 1` == `'2' + 2` == `'1' + 3` == `'0' + 4`.

And in general, the digit character for any number from 0 to 9 can be found by adding that number to the character `'0'`.